# How to use binary search of a sorted list and then count the comparisons

Tags: java, search, binary

I am trying to use my sorted list and implement it with binary search. Then i want to count the number of comparisons it takes to find the key. my code is:

```
public class BinarySearch {
    private static int comparisions = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

        int i = BinarySearch.BinSearch(list, 20);

        System.out.println(comparisions);
    }

    public static int BinSearch(int[] list, int key) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = list.length - 1;
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;

        if (key < list[mid]) {
            high = mid - 1;
            comparisions++;
        } else if (key == list[mid]) {
            return mid;
            comparisions++;  
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
            comparisions++;
        }

        return -1;          
    }
}
```

So far it only gives me 1 for the comparison no matter what number is the key.

Comment: this should not compile since the middle `comparisions++` is unreachable. And it does not work since you are missing the *loop* part of the search.

Comment: Have you tried actually printing out the index you get? Because your code is not doing binary search (at least not past the first step).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the looping part of the search, that looping can either be done using recursion or using a `while` loop. In both cases you have to ask yourself wether or not you just want to *know* the count or actually return the count of comparisons. Since your method right now returns the index, it cannot easily return the count of comparisons at the same time. For that to work you either need to return an array of two ints or a custom `class IndexAndComparisonCount { ... }`.

*If* you use a recursive approach you need to increment whenever you do a comparison and when you do a recursive call you need to get the return value of that recursive call and increment the comparisonCount the call returned by 1:

```
if (... < ...) {
    IndexAndComparisonCount ret = BinSearch(...);
    ret.comparisonCount += 1;
    return ret;
} else if (... > ...) {
    IndexAndComparisonCount ret = BinSearch(...);
    ret.comparisonCount += 2; // since you did compare twice already
    return ret;
} else {
    return new IndexAndComparisonCount(mid, 2); // you compared twice as well
}
```